# How to model has_one of each type (using enum) of other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Apologies if this question has been asked somewhere else in a different way, but I'm not 100% sure how to word it.

I'm working with code someone else has created. They created a model in Rails called "Contact" (as in a contact for a company) and used enum to create 4 different types of contacts - billing, materials, primary, and other.

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    enum contact_type_id: [:Billing, :Materials, :Primary, :Other]
    ...
end
```

I need to create a model called "SalesOrder" that has 3 contacts for each record. One primary contact, one billing contact, and one materials contact. Only one contact of each kind can go on a sales order. Using a many-to-many relationship doesn't seem like it's going to work.

The way I've been trying to do this is by creating three join tables: contact_sales_order_primary, contact_sales_order_billing, and contact_sales_order_material. That way the SalesOrder model can use has_one for each of these tables, while the Contact model can use has_many for the tables.

This is what I've been trying, but I can't get it to work (I've also looked into STI and polymorphic associations, but those don't seem to exactly fit the bill). I can't tell if:

1. I'm taking the right approach to this problem and I just haven't figured out how to properly execute it yet,
2. it's overkill and I should be doing something simpler, or
3. if there is an entirely different method that I'm overlooking

And of course, I can provide any additional details you might need to help answer. Any help or advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Did not see that kind of an approach.. why do you say that many to many won't work? What did you try?

Comment: Many-to-many won't work in this use case because each sales order needs to have exactly one primary contact, exactly one billing contact, and exactly one material contact and should not be able to have multiple contacts for any of these fields. But if there's something I'm not understanding about the many_to_many relationship let me know.

Comment: You could have something like order_sale_contacts with unique index on the combination on [order_id, contact_id, contact_type_id]

Comment: Ah okay. I'll definitely give that a try. Would the unique indices be in the order_sale_contacts table?